# How do I compute a date a specified period in the future?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this:

```
string dataNow = DateTime.Today.tostring();
string dateAfter = dateNow + ( 20 days);
```

How do I find the date in 20 days?
How do I find the number of days in the month?

Answer (score 7):

Your likely intent is to work with a date as a date type `DateTime`. In which case, don't call `ToString()` before you've completed manipulating the date:

```
string dataNow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(20).ToString();
```

[DateTime.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

---

After update:

To get the number of days in the current month:

```
var date = DateTime.Today;
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
```

[DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx)

Comment: @CyberDx: Note that you should consider to accept answers when they solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
    DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Today;
    string dateNow = dtNow.ToString();
    string dateAfter = dtNow.AddDays(20).ToString();
    int DaysInTheMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dtNow.Year, dtNow.Month);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime later = today.AddDays(20);

string todayAsString = today.ToString("d");
string laterAsString = later.ToString("d");

int daysThisMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month);
int daysLaterMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(later.Year, later.Month);
```